# Can't reset index for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, counter, reset

I want to create a program which can be used for an ATM. This is what I've made:

```
# 500, 20, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1
nrb = 0
i=0
j=0
bancnote = [500, 200, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1]
for i in range(7):
    print('b:',bancnote[i])
suma = int(input('Scrieti suma dorita: '))
while suma > 0:
    while j <= 6:
        if suma >= bancnote[j]:
            nrb +=1
            suma -=bancnote[j]
            print('Am scazut: ', bancnote[j])
            print('Ramas: ',suma)
            print("Bancnote: ",nrb)
            j=0
```

My counter for that loop can't be reset. What can I do?

Comment: Please post the code instead of the picture, easier for other people to copy across and work for a solution.

Comment: Your code should be provided as text and not image, so we can reproduce your problem

Comment: Put code here and let us know exactly which loop is causing problem..

Comment: That's the code: # bancomat cu bancnote de:
`# 500, 20, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1

nrb = 0
i=0
j=0
bancnote = [500, 200, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1]
for i in range(7):
    print('b:',bancnote[i])
suma = int(input('Scrieti suma dorita: '))
while suma > 0:
    while j <= 6:
        if suma >= bancnote[j]:
            nrb +=1
            suma -=bancnote[j]
            print('Am scazut: ', bancnote[j])
            print('Ramas: ',suma)
            print("Bancnote: ",nrb)
            j=0`

Comment: Sorry for text formatting...

Comment: What do you mean? What counter, and what loop? There are multiple of each. What should be the _expected_ output for that program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It is easier for me to understand the code as I can read the language as well)

What you forgot is to increment `j`, so your code will only look at the 500 bank note every time. Thus not trying to decrease other value from the sum.

Answer (score 1):

there is no increment in variable `j` . so the loop will remain as it is

Answer (score 0):

Your indices are not really required by Python.
Considering what I understood from the problem, the code should look similar to this:

```
note_values = (500, 200, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1)

def partition(value):
    result = []
    for note in note_values:
        whole, value = divmod(value, note)
        result.append(whole)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    value = int(input("Sum wanted: "))
    notes = partition(value)
    for number, value in zip(notes, note_values):
        if number != 0:
            print("{} note of {:3d}".format(number, value))
```